# Ошибка подключения к прокси requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: python, get, proxy

Не получается подключится через проксю к сайту ,вываливается ошибка:
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https://example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy. Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: [https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy'](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy%27), SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))))

```
import requests

proxies = {
'https': 'HTTPS://144.217.119.85:3207'}

url = 'https://example.com'
response = requests.get(url,proxies=proxies)

if response.status_code == 200:  
    print(response)
```

Поставил:

```
proxies = {'SOCKS5': 'SOCKS5://98.162.25.23:4145'}
```

вроде ошибки нет, но написал код проверки, выдает мой ip.А не должен ведь

```
url = 'https://httpbin.org/ip'
response = requests.get(url,proxies=proxies)
data = response.json()
ip = data['origin']
print(ip)
```

кароче пошел другим путем.есть аваст VPN.включил его.Он скрыл мой ip .но код при этом выдает начальное сообщение requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool даже не использую в коде proxies а просто

```
requests.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url = 'http://example.com'
```

Он ругается, на то что ты твои прокси работают только с протоколом http, соответственно измени url на http

Comment: уже не ругается.ответ 200 но айпи не скрывает все равно